# Data.com Match Criteria

Tags: data.com

I am having some issues getting matches using the Data.com Match API.  I am able to get matches using the Google example in Data.com's documentation, however, I have been unsuccessful when trying to match other companies.  I am using Fiddler to make the requests.

I know that the *attributes* property has to come first, but does order matter on any of the other properties?  I have tried ordering my properties to match the Google example, but still had no luck.  Are there certain properties that will increase my chance of a match?  Has anyone else had any luck matching using this API and, if so, could you provide some guidance?

I am submitting a request with the following companies as entities:

```
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "DatacloudCompany"
      },
      "Name": "Google",
      "Website": "www.google.com",
      "Phone": "+1.650.253.0000",
      "City": "Mountain View"
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "DatacloudCompany"
      },
      "Name": "Bob Evans Farms",
      "Website": "www.bobevans.com",
      "Phone": "+1.614.491.2225",
      "City": "New Albany"
    }
  ],
  "fields": [
    "AnnualRevenue",
    "City",
    "CompanyId",
    "Country",
    "Description",
    "DunsNumber",
    "Fax",
    "Industry",
    "IsInactive",
    "NaicsCode",
    "NaicsDesc",
    "Name",
    "NumberOfEmployees",
    "Ownership",
    "Phone",
    "Sic",
    "SicDesc",
    "State",
    "TickerSymbol",
    "TradeStyle",
    "Website",
    "YearStarted",
    "Zip",
    "Site"
  ]
}
```

I am receiving the following response:

```
[
  {
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "matchRecords": [
      {
        "entity": {
          "attributes": {
            "type": "DatacloudCompany"
          },
          "Name": "Google, Inc.",
          "Website": "www.google.com",
          "SicDesc": "Information Retrieval Services",
          "DunsNumber": "000215043",
          "Phone": "+1.650.253.0000",
          "TickerSymbol": "GOOG",
          "CompanyId": 215043,
          "AnnualRevenue": 7.517914E+08,
          "NumberOfEmployees": 6150,
          "Zip": "94043-1351",
          "NaicsCode": "517919",
          "Description": "",
          "Site": "Headquarters",
          "Fax": "",
          "YearStarted": "1997",
          "Country": "United States",
          "City": "Mountain View",
          "State": "CA",
          "TradeStyle": "",
          "NaicsDesc": "All Other Telecommunications",
          "IsInactive": false,
          "Ownership": "Public",
          "Sic": "7375",
          "Industry": "Technology"
        },
        "matchDiffs": [
          "Name"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "errorCode": 0,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "matchRecords": []
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, ever figure it out?